# How to detect when file reached its maximum size with android's MediaRecorder?

Tags: java, android, file, api, mediarecorder

While recording video with Android's `MediaRecorder` how to detect and display `Toast` message when video file being recorded has reached its maximum size and file is being saved (or is about to be saved)?

EDIT: This is code I currently have but callback is not triggered although file is successfully saved.

```
final Context activity=this.getBaseContext();

mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {

    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(what==MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED)
         Toast.makeText(activity, "There is no more space available. Video recording is stopped now.",2000).show();

    }
});

// getBytesAvailable() returns bytes available on sdcard
mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(getBytesAvailable());

mediaRecorder.prepare();
```

Comment: ``MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener`` seems to have ``MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED`` error message, maybe it gave you means to show a Toast?

Comment: I added code I have at the moment but the callback is not triggered when the file reaches its max size. Where I go wrong?

Comment: You are using constant value ``2000`` for Toast length, maybe you should use ``Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`` or ``Toast.LENGTH_LONG`` instead?

Comment: ahh tried Toast.LENGTH_LONG, mad no difference :(

Comment: Ah I see. One thing you could try is to check whether you receive any notifications to OnInfoListener, not only max file size. This is a long shot though..

Comment: yeh it enters callback actually but "what" is almost never equalled to MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED. It was equalled maybe twice out of 50 tries and I cant really get it working

Comment: and thanks for trying to help Harism, I appreciate that

Answer (score 5):

MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED means the file has reached its maximum size; there may well be more space on the SD card, but something has forbidden the current recording file from growing any larger.  This is usually due to a call to [MediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setMaxFileSize%28long%29).  If you don't call this method, you won't get the INFO, though you might when the file reaches the 2GB limit of the FAT file system.

I can't find a clear answer as to what happens when you run out of space; some people seem to think onError will be called with what == MEDIA_RECORDER_ERROR_UNKNOWN.

So in other words, call setMaxFileSize() with a size equal to a few seconds of recording. Your callback should work then.